# global variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check whether the global variable return null. def C() is called in a click event which means patientName wont be assigned obviously. However, I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have this code below:

```
class Example(): 
  patientName = 0

  def A(): 
    global patientName 
    patientName = "12"

  def B(): 
    print (patientName) #prints 12

  def C(): 
    #I want to check if patientName = null here 
    #how to do it? 
    #Assume C is triggered by the click event. 
    if patientName!="123" --> throws global variable patientName 
                            referenced before assignment....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem related to java

Comment: Your "global" variable is a class attribute, to access it you can just use `Example.patientName`. Overall your code doesn't look too good. You should read some tutorials about OOP if you try to use classes properly. (and remove the java tag, this is clearly python, although it's weird python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class Example(): 
  patientName = None

  def A(self): 

    self.patientName = "12"

  def B(self): 
    print (self.patientName) #prints 12

  def C(self): 
    #I want to check if patientName = null here 
    #how to do it? 
    #Assume C is triggered by the click event. 
    if(self.patientName==None):
        print("do something")
```

Here is the example to run your check

```
ex=Example()
ex.A()
ex.C()
```

Answer (score 0):

You either want this, with patientName being a global name

```
patientName = 0

class Example(): 

  def A(): 
    global patientName 
    patientName = "12"

  def B(): 
    print (patientName) #prints 12

  def C(): 
    if patientName!="123"
```

or more probably you want something like this

```
class Patient():

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def C(self): 
    if self.name!="Sally":
       # do something

patient1 = Patient("Mary")
print(patient1.name) # Mary
patient1.C()
```

A global name will be in outer scope and any time you want to write its value in an inner scope you'll have to declare it global beforehand in that scope. For reads the normal scope rules will do, no need for the global statement. But probably you want to create different instances of `Patient`. That is the second suggestion. Defining a name inside a class
but outside any methods makes it a class name, that is a name shared by all instances (unless an instance assigns `somename` as `self.somename` hiding the shared `Patient.somename`). I assume you want the name associated with each instance and not a shared class name, that's why I assign it using `self`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you could simply try

```
if( patientName!== 'undefined' ) {
    // foo could get resolved and it's defined
}
```